# REGEX match unlimited of one character but only two of another

Tags: regex

I would like to capture a string with the longest possible amount of one character followed by no more than two of another character.
Example:

```
aaaaabbbbbbbb
```

Would capture:

```
aaaaabb, bb and b
```

I have tried:

```
(a*)(b)(?!\2{2})
```

but this is only grabbing the two b's like so:

```
bb
```

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/g6vuUZ/5

Comment: Why does it only capture `b`, not all the other `bb` pairs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a*b{0,2}
```

This matches any number of `a` followed by up to 2 `b`.

When using your input, it matches

```
aaaaabb
bb
bb
bb
```

Since `{0,2}` is greedy, it always matches pairs of `b`, not just a single one. It matches all the remaining `bb` because they're preceded by zero `a`, which is matched by `a*`.

[DEMO](http://aaaaabb)